# Shader Option Missing

Tags: shaders

When adding a material, I'd like to add a shader. Not sure why it's not showing up. Am I missing something? I'm using Blender 2.78

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see shader nodes because you are using Blender Render.

[image]

Switch to Cycles Render, then you can add shader nodes by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shader > add shader